# how to display a big amount of data in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, output

so I made a pyhton program that has outputs like this :

```
Results :
23 ---- 30.056818181818183

36 ---- 47.04545454545455

49 ---- 64.0340909090909

62 ---- 81.02272727272727

72 ---- 94.0909090909091

75 ---- 98.01136363636364
```

this one is  a bit short but some times it has to be longer. I wanted to create a tkinter program for it but tkinter window is small for this and if I make it bigger it will be so cluttered and bad looking. do you know a good way to store this amount of data in a good way ? like in a table or etc.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned tkinter I believe you want to see these results on a GUI. If so I suggest using text widget, since it has textwrap feature. But still it will be ugly. Another approach would be;

1. You can write them into csv file ( sample script below);

   ```
   import csv

   header = ['name', 'area', 'country_code2', 'country_code3']
   data = ['Afghanistan', 652090, 'AF', 'AFG']


   with open('countries.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)

        # write the header
        writer.writerow(header)

        # write the data
        writer.writerow(data)
   ```
2. Or Store your results as DataFrame using pandas Library. With pandas you can create Dataframes from lists, dictionaries , etc

   ```
    import pandas as pd

    data={'Name':['Karan','Rohit','Sahil','Aryan'],'Age':[23,22,21,24]}

    df=pd.dataframe(data)

    df #print the dataframe
   ```